# why docker-compose work and docker run doesn't

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I have the following local.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  celery-worker-default:
    image: weapp_app:latest
    container_name: weapp_celery-worker-default
    command: celery worker -A WeApp -Q default -n default --loglevel=INFO
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/python/current/app/
```

When I run

```
docker-compose -f local.yml up celery-worker-default
```

everything work great
also running like

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run celery-worker-default celery worker -A WeApp -Q default -n default --loglevel=INFO
```

Everything run OK

But If I try to execute with docker with the following command

```
docker run -v "$(pwd):/opt/python/current/app/" -w /opt/python/current/app --env-file .env weapp_app:latest celery worker -A WeApp -Q default -n default --loglevel=INFO
```

I get this error

```
Error: 
Unable to load celery application.
The module "WeApp was not found.
```

I already try change $(pwd) for the local complete local path but I get the same error.

In other way I try to pass all the environment value by command line with option -e and get the same error.
I try without working directory in the docker options.
I try opening a shell inside the container and execute the command, but the same error.

Comment: The main difference I see is the workdir (`-w`). Try without!

Comment: I already try without workdir and I get the same error

Comment: I looks like its your `-A WeApp` have you tried removing that? I don't see the `-A` documented in `docker run` what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Both the Compose `volumes:` and the `docker run -v` option look like they're overwriting the code in the image and replacing it with something else; if they're not replacing it with the same thing and something that matches the image layout then you could have this problem.  If you delete the `-w` _and_ the `-v` options, to use the code built into the image, does it work better?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but  -A option it is for celery,  to use WeApp application, then is a parameter for celery not for docker. In other way I try without -v option and without -w option and the result was the same error.

Comment: Do a `docker ps -a` to see the Ids of the containers created by compose and by docker. Then use `docker inspect <id>` and dump it to a json file. Then do diff between then two and see if you can find a proper delta between the two containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Thanks to everybody who commented and help with theirs ideas

After follow Tarun's comment, I could see the problem, but I think is good to everyone know about it.

The environment file (in my case .env) is read in a different way by docker-compose than docker.

Then when you use docker-compose you can declare the values like

```
VAR="VALUE"
```

But for docker you must have to declare like

```
VAR=VALUE
```

without quotation marks.
This made all the difference in my case.

Thanks again to everyone who took a time to read my post.